# JavaScript - output values from two different dropdown menus

Tags: javascript

I'm still new to Java Script, I'm trying to create a very simple tool, but I have some questions I can't seem to figure out how. Hope any of you can give me some ideas or examples here.

I have two drop down menus and I want to output the selected values and displayed them in a readable way. How can I use document.getElementId and onchange to write a function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Example,

Moving from (value from list_1) to (value from list_2)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<div class="moving_1">
<span>* Moving from:</span><br/>
<select name="list_1" id="list_1">
<option value="CA">CA</option>
<option value="DC">DC</option>
<option value="PA">PA</option>
<option value="NY">NY</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="moving_2">
<span>* Moving to:</span><br/>
<select name="list_2" id="list_2">
<option value="CA">CA</option>
<option value="DC">DC</option>
<option value="PA">PA</option>
<option value="NY">NY</option>
</select>
</div>

<p>Moving from (value from list_1) to (value from list_2)</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps. If you have any questions, just ask in comments.

```js
// We find element by id "list_1" then we add an event listener "change"
document.getElementById("list_1").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  // Now we find element by id "moving_1_result" and set its innerHTML to targets value aka list_2's value
  document.getElementById("moving_1_result").innerHTML = e.target.value;
});

document.getElementById("list_2").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  document.getElementById("moving_2_result").innerHTML = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<div class="moving_1">
  <span>* Moving from: <span id="moving_1_result"></span></span>
  <br/>
  <select name="list_1" id="list_1">
    <option value="CA">CA</option>
    <option value="DC">DC</option>
    <option value="PA">PA</option>
    <option value="NY">NY</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="moving_2">
  <span>* Moving to: <span id="moving_2_result"></span></span>
  <br/>
  <select name="list_2" id="list_2">
    <option value="CA">CA</option>
    <option value="DC">DC</option>
    <option value="PA">PA</option>
    <option value="NY">NY</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Device - thanks for the help. I see three different approaches, I will see how much I can learn from those examples :)

Answer (score 0):

it relatively easy, try the following

```js
//onchange handler
function changed(listId){
  var  list = document.getElementById(listId);
  document.getElementById("val_"+listId).innerHTML = list.value;
}

//initialization
document.getElementById("val_list_1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("list_1").value;
document.getElementById("val_list_2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("list_2").value;
```

```html
<div class="moving_1">
<span>* Moving from:</span><br/>
<select onchange="changed('list_1')" name="list_1" id="list_1">
<option value="CA">CA</option>
<option value="DC">DC</option>
<option value="PA">PA</option>
<option value="NY">NY</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="moving_2">
<span>* Moving to:</span><br/>
<select onchange="changed('list_2')" name="list_2" id="list_2">
<option value="CA">CA</option>
<option value="DC">DC</option>
<option value="PA">PA</option>
<option value="NY">NY</option>
</select>
</div>

<p>Moving from <span id="val_list_1"></span> to <span id="val_list_2"></span></p>
```

Comment: Hi @coding-due.com - thanks for the help, I see the approach from you, this actually works. Thanks for the help again. I will continue to learn more :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's stay with your original code. You would need to add an [eventListener](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) to your dropdown menus and then overwrite the [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) of your paragraph.
You can identify your elements either by their [class name](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) or by their [tag name](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp).

It is preferable to have IDs and not just class names to make the identification process easier.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("moving_1")[0].addEventListener("change", update_text);
document.getElementsByClassName("moving_2")[0].addEventListener("change", update_text);

function update_text() {
    document.getElementById("moving_text").innerHTML = "Moving from " + document.getElementsByClassName("moving_1")[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value + " to " + document.getElementsByClassName("moving_2")[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value;

}
```

```html
<div class="moving_1">
    <span>* Moving from:</span><br/>
    <select name="list_1" id="list_1">
        <option value="CA">CA</option>
        <option value="DC">DC</option>
        <option value="PA">PA</option>
        <option value="NY">NY</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="moving_2">
    <span>* Moving to:</span><br/>
    <select name="list_2" id="list_2">
        <option value="CA">CA</option>
        <option value="DC">DC</option>
        <option value="PA">PA</option>
        <option value="NY">NY</option>
    </select>
</div>

<p id="moving_text">Moving from (value from list_1) to (value from list_2)</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Maimilian Peters for the explanation!